# Lost connection to "iPhone 6”.when first time run my iOS app in xcode6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

I am using Xcode6.0.1, first time run my app in iOS simulator then I got following error message

> Restore the connection to "iPhone 6" and run “APPNAME” again, or if
>   "APPNAME" is still running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug >
>   Attach to Process > APPNAME.

How do I solve this issue?

[image: Screenshot for error]

Comment: I have never seen that issue, but first time running an app on iOS 8 now gives me a "Security" error. Turns out that I had to launch the app manually myself because there was a prompt asking If i wanted to trust the developer certificate... Something that Xcode couldn't bypass until I had physically allowed it myself... Could that be your issue? Or is the application not even getting installed on the device?

Comment: @user:Please accept the answers or upvote it they were useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and should be mentioned in the release notes.  At present, the only workaround is to try again.  Sorry.  =/

Answer (score 1):

You can  select Debug in menu bar and select attach to process and select iOS Simulator. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the simulator content and settings and launch the simulator again.

That worked for me.

Hope it helps someone else also.

Answer (score 0):

This happens less frequently in Xcode 6.1 as compared to Xcode 6 beta version.
Only **solution is to Re-run your project**. This seems to be bug and might be fixed in upcoming Xcode 6.2 version.

This persists in Xcode 6.2.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the projects and re-run it then you will find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Just close simulator and Re-Run project this work for time.

Answer (score 0):

delete the same name of existing project and re run the project 
means  if you are run the helloworld project then delete helloworld project from the device if you run in past then re-build project again.it worked for me.